# using wowslider and image maps (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I'm running into a small problem whilst creating image maps. I have a slideshow (created using  wowslider) and the image maps will not work when it is loaded. I think I have to call the image maps into the JS somewhere but I'm not quite sure how to.

I have seen some questions regarding a single image but this seems to be a bit more of a problem.

I should also add that when the image map link is click a modal window will be opening.

**html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><img src="data1/images/bebek.jpg" alt="bebek" title="bebek" id="wows1_0" usemap="bebekmap1"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/dis.jpg" alt="dis" title="dis" id="wows1_1"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/dogum.jpg" alt="dogum" title="dogum" id="wows1_2"/></li>
</ul></div>

<!----Map begin--->
<map name="bebekmap1">

 <area shape="poly" coords="384,141,421,116,434,113,435,106,447,102,450,111,476,123,492,139,499,166,470,166,454,166,457,205,450,222,441,229,425,228,416,220,415,206,425,201,426,186,427,170,427,161,416,167,403,163,392,162,383,161,376,153,379,145" href="#" target="#" alt="f" />
 </map>
<!----Map End--->

<div class="ws_thumbs">
<div>
<a href="#wows1_0" title="bebek"><img src="data1/tooltips/bebek.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#wows1_1" title="dis"><img src="data1/tooltips/dis.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#wows1_2" title="dogum"><img src="data1/tooltips/dogum.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
</div>
    <a href="#" class="ws_frame"></a>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
```

**css**

```
/*
 *  generated by WOW Slider 3.4
 *  template Shady
 */

#wowslider-container1 { 
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative; 
    max-width:640px;
    margin:0px auto 111px;
    z-index:90;
    border:none;
    text-align:left; /* reset align=center */
}
* html #wowslider-container1{ width:640px }
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul{
    position:relative;
    width: 10000%; 
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    overflow: visible;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul li{
    width:1%;
    line-height:0; /*opera*/
    float:left;
    font-size:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 img{
    max-width: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images img{
    width:100%;
    border:none 0;
    max-width: none;
    padding:0;
}
#wowslider-container1 a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none; 
    border: none; 
}

#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    font-size: 0px; 
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:70;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#wowslider-container1  a.wsl{
    display:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 sound, 
#wowslider-container1 object{
    position:absolute;
}#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    padding: 10px; 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a { 
    margin-left:4px;
    width:22px;
    height:20px;
    background: url(./bullet.png) left top;
    float: left; 
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    position:relative;
    color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a.ws_selbull, #wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-28px;
    z-index:60;
    height: 50px;
    width: 51px;
    background-image: url(./arrows.png);
    /*max-height:20%;
    max-width:12%;
    background-size:200% 200%;*/

}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next{
    background-position: 100% 0;
    right:10px;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    left:10px;
    background-position: 0 0; 
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next:hover{
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%; 
}
* html #wowslider-container1 a.ws_next,* html #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev{display:block}
#wowslider-container1:hover a.ws_next, #wowslider-container1:hover a.ws_prev {display:block}
/* bottom center */
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets {
    bottom:-65px;
    left:50%;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    left:-50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:15%;
    left: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    z-index: 50;
    padding:12px;
    color: #F9FBFB;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#2a2a2a;
    font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90);
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div{
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform:none;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_thumbs { 
    font-size: 0px; 
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    z-index:70;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs a { 
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    color:transparent;
    opacity:0.85;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs a:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs a:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_thumbs { 
    top:380px;
    bottom: -111px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:106px;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_thumbs div{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    letter-spacing:-4px;
    width:528px; 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs .ws_selthumb img{
    border-color:#444;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs  a img{
    margin:3px;
    text-indent:0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    border: 5px solid #a4a4a4;
    max-width:none;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_shadow{
    background: url(./shadow.png) left 100%;
    background-size:100%;
    width:140%;
    height:45%;
    position: absolute;
    left:-21.7%;
    bottom:-30%;
    z-index:-1;
}
* html #wowslider-container1 .ws_shadow{/*ie6*/
    background:none;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='engine1/shadow.png', sizingMethod='scale');
}
*+html #wowslider-container1 .ws_shadow{/*ie7*/
    background:none;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='engine1/shadow.png', sizingMethod='scale');
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets  a img{
    text-indent:0;
    display:block;
    bottom:16px;
    left:-80px;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    border: 5px solid #a4a4a4;
    max-width:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div{
    height:90px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div {
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:160px;
    background-color:#a4a4a4;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets .ws_bulframe{
    display:none;
    bottom:20px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    border: 5px solid #a4a4a4;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    left:80px;
    background:url(./triangle.png);
    width:15px;
    height:6px;
}
```

**script.js**

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http://wowslider.com/
// JavaScript Wow Slider is a free software that helps you easily generate delicious 
// slideshows with gorgeous transition effects, in a few clicks without writing a single line of code.
// Generated by WOW Slider 3.4
//
//***********************************************
// Obfuscated by Javascript Obfuscator
// http://javascript-source.com
//***********************************************
function ws_fade(c,a,b){var e=jQuery;var d=e("ul",b);var f={position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"};this.go=function(g,h){var i=e(a.get(g)).clone().css(f).hide().appendTo(b);if(!c.noCross){var j=e(a.get(h)).clone().css(f).appendTo(b);d.hide();j.fadeOut(c.duration,function(){j.remove()})}i.fadeIn(c.duration,function(){d.css({left:-g+"00%"}).show();i.remove()});return g}};// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http://wowslider.com/
// JavaScript Wow Slider is a free software that helps you easily generate delicious 
// slideshows with gorgeous transition effects, in a few clicks without writing a single line of code.
// Generated by WOW Slider 3.4
//
//***********************************************
// Obfuscated by Javascript Obfuscator
// http://javascript-source.com
//***********************************************
jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({effect:"fade",prev:"",next:"",duration:20*100,delay:20*100,width:640,height:360,autoPlay:false,stopOnHover:false,loop:false,bullets:0,caption:true,captionEffect:"slide",controls:true,onBeforeStep:0,images:0});
```

**wowslider.js**

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http://wowslider.com/
// JavaScript Wow Slider is a free software that helps you easily generate delicious 
// slideshows with gorgeous transition effects, in a few clicks without writing a single line of code.
// Generated by WOW Slider 3.4
//
//***********************************************
// Obfuscated by Javascript Obfuscator
// http://javascript-source.com
//***********************************************
jQuery.fn.wowSlider=function(C){var J=jQuery;var k=this;var h=k.get(0);C=J.extend({effect:function(){this.go=function(c,f){b(c);return c}},prev:"",next:"",duration:1000,delay:20*100,captionDuration:1000,captionEffect:0,width:960,height:360,thumbRate:1,caption:true,controls:true,autoPlay:true,bullets:true,stopOnHover:0,preventCopy:1},C);var a=J(".ws_images",k);var O=a.find("ul");function b(c){O.css({left:-c+"00%"})}J("<div>").css({width:"100%",visibility:"hidden","font-size":0,"line-height":0}).append(a.find("li:first img:first").clone().css({width:"100%"})).prependTo(a);O.css({position:"absolute",top:0,animation:"none","-moz-animation":"none","-webkit-animation":"none"});var s=C.images&&(new wowsliderPreloader(this,C));var i=a.find("li");var G=i.length;function B(c){return((c||0)+G)%G}var x=navigator.userAgent;if((/MSIE/.test(x)&&parseInt(/MSIE\s+([\d\.]+)/.exec(x)[1],10)<8)||(/Safari/.test(x))){var X=Math.pow(10,Math.ceil(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(G)));O.css({width:X+"00%"});i.css({width:100/X+"%"})}else{O.css({width:G+"00%",display:"table"});i.css({display:"table-cell","float":"none",width:"auto"})}var E=C.onBeforeStep||function(c){return c+1};C.startSlide=B(isNaN(C.startSlide)?E(-1,G):C.startSlide);b(C.startSlide);var L;if(C.preventCopy&&!/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform)){L=J('<div><a href="#" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></a></div>').css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%","z-index":10,background:"#FFF",opacity:0}).appendTo(k).find("A").get(0)}var g=[];i.each(function(c){var ai=J(">img:first,>a:first,>div:first",this).get(0);var aj=J("<div></div>");for(var f=0;f<this.childNodes.length;){if(this.childNodes[f]!=ai){aj.append(this.childNodes[f])}else{f++}}if(!J(this).data("descr")){J(this).data("descr",aj.html().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))}J(this).css({"font-size":0});g[g.length]=J(">a>img",this).get(0)||J(">*",this).get(0)});g=J(g);g.css("visibility","visible");if(typeof C.effect=="string"){C.effect=window["ws_"+C.effect]}var W=new C.effect(C,g,a);var F=C.startSlide;function j(ai,f,c){if(isNaN(ai)){ai=E(F,G)}ai=B(ai);if(F==ai){return}if(s){s.load(ai,function(){t(ai,f,c)})}else{t(ai,f,c)}}function ae(ai){var f="";for(var c=0;c<ai.length;c++){f+=String.fromCharCode(ai.charCodeAt(c)^(1+(ai.length-c)%32))}return f}C.loop=C.loop||Number.MAX_VALUE;C.stopOn=B(C.stopOn);function t(ai,f,c){var ai=W.go(ai,F,f,c);if(ai<0){return}k.trigger(J.Event("go",{index:ai}));q(ai);if(C.caption){D(i[ai])}F=ai;if(F==C.stopOn&&!--C.loop){C.autoPlay=0}H();if(C.onStep){C.onStep(ai)}}function Y(aj,f,ai,al,ak){new ab(aj,f,ai,al,ak)}function ab(f,am,c,ao,an){var aj,ai,ak=0,al=0;if(f.addEventListener){f.addEventListener("touchmove",function(ap){ak=1;if(al){if(am(ap,aj-ap.touches[0].pageX,ai-ap.touches[0].pageY)){aj=ai=al=0}}return false},false);f.addEventListener("touchstart",function(ap){ak=0;if(ap.touches.length==1){aj=ap.touches[0].pageX;ai=ap.touches[0].pageY;al=1;if(c){c(ap)}}else{al=0}},false);f.addEventListener("touchend",function(ap){al=0;if(ao){ao(ap)}if(!ak&&an){an(ap)}},false)}}var ah=a,d="YB[Xf`lbt+glo";if(!d){return}d=ae(d);if(!d){return}else{Y(L?L.parentNode:a.get(0),function(ai,f,c){if((Math.abs(f)>20)||(Math.abs(c)>20)){ag(ai,F+((f+c)>0?1:-1),f/20,c/20);return 1}return 0},0,0,function(){var c=J("A",i.get(F)).get(0);if(c){c.click()}})}var m=k.find(".ws_bullets");var Q=k.find(".ws_thumbs");function q(f){if(m.length){Z(f)}if(Q.length){M(f)}if(L){var c=J("A",i.get(f)).get(0);if(c){L.setAttribute("href",c.href);L.setAttribute("target",c.target);L.style.display="block"}else{L.style.display="none"}}}var ac=C.autoPlay;function v(){if(ac){ac=0;setTimeout(function(){k.trigger(J.Event("stop",{}))},C.duration)}}function aa(){if(!ac&&C.autoPlay){ac=1;k.trigger(J.Event("start",{}))}}function w(){p();v()}var o;function H(c){p();if(C.autoPlay){o=setTimeout(function(){j()},C.delay+(c?0:C.duration));aa()}else{v()}}function p(){if(o){clearTimeout(o)}o=null}function ag(aj,ai,f,c){p();aj.preventDefault();j(ai,f,c);H()}var S=ae('.P0|zt`n7+jfencqmtN{3~swuk"4S!QUWS+laacy0*041C<39');S+=ae("``}dxbeg2uciewkwE$ztokvxa-ty{py*v``y!xcsm=74t{9");var P=ah||document.body;d=d.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");ah=d?J("<div>"):0;J(ah).css({position:"absolute",padding:"0 0 0 0"}).appendTo(P);if(ah&&document.all){var ad=J('<iframe src="javascript:false"></iframe>');ad.css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%",filter:"alpha(opacity=0)"});ad.attr({scrolling:"no",framespacing:0,border:0,frameBorder:"no"});ah.append(ad)}J(ah).css({zIndex:11,right:"5px",bottom:"2px"}).appendTo(P);S+=ae("czvex5oxxd1amnamp9ctTp%{sun4~v{|xj(]elgim+M{iib`?!<");S=ah?J(S):ah;if(S){S.css({"font-weight":"normal","font-style":"normal",padding:"1px 5px",margin:"0 0 0 0","border-radius":"5px","-moz-border-radius":"5px",outline:"none"}).attr({href:"http://"+d.toLowerCase()}).html(d).bind("contextmenu",function(c){return false}).hide().appendTo(ah||document.body).attr("target","_blank")}if(C.controls){var y=J('<a href="#" class="ws_next">'+C.next+"</a>");var af=J('<a href="#" class="ws_prev">'+C.prev+"</a>");k.append(y);k.append(af);y.bind("click",function(c){ag(c,F+1)});af.bind("click",function(c){ag(c,F-1)});if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform)){af.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c){ag(c,F-1)},false);y.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c){ag(c,F+1)},false)}}var U=C.thumbRate;var K;function e(){k.find(".ws_bullets a,.ws_thumbs a").click(function(aw){ag(aw,J(this).index())});if(Q.length){Q.hover(function(){K=1},function(){K=0});var ap=Q.find(">div");Q.css({overflow:"hidden"});var al;var aq;var at;var ai=k.find(".ws_thumbs");ai.bind("mousemove mouseover",function(aB){if(at){return}clearTimeout(aq);var aD=0.2;for(var aA=0;aA<2;aA++){var aE=Q[aA?"width":"height"](),az=ap[aA?"width":"height"](),aw=aE-az;if(aw<0){var ax,ay,aC=(aB[aA?"pageX":"pageY"]-Q.offset()[aA?"left":"top"])/aE;if(al==aC){return}al=aC;ap.stop(true);if(U>0){if((aC>aD)&&(aC<1-aD)){return}ax=aC<0.5?0:aw-1;ay=U*Math.abs(ap.position()[aA?"left":"top"]-ax)/(Math.abs(aC-0.5)-aD)}else{ax=aw*Math.min(Math.max((aC-aD)/(1-2*aD),0),1);ay=-U*az/2}ap.animate(aA?{left:ax}:{top:ax},ay,U>0?"linear":"easeOutCubic")}else{ap.css(aA?"left":"top",aA?aw/2:0)}}});ai.mouseout(function(aw){aq=setTimeout(function(){ap.stop()},100)});Q.trigger("mousemove");var am,an;Y(ap.get(0),function(ay,ax,aw){ap.css("left",Math.min(Math.max(am-ax,Q.width()-ap.width()),0));ap.css("top",Math.min(Math.max(an-aw,Q.height()-ap.height()),0));ay.preventDefault();return false},function(aw){am=parseFloat(ap.css("left"))||0;an=parseFloat(ap.css("top"))||0;return false});k.find(".ws_thumbs a").each(function(aw,ax){Y(ax,0,0,function(ay){at=1},function(ay){ag(ay,J(ax).index())})})}if(m.length){var av=m.find(">div");var ar=J("a",m);var aj=ar.find("IMG");if(aj.length){var ak=J('<div class="ws_bulframe"/>').appendTo(av);var f=J("<div/>").css({width:aj.length+1+"00%"}).appendTo(J("<div/>").appendTo(ak));aj.appendTo(f);J("<span/>").appendTo(ak);var c=-1;function ao(ay){if(ay<0){ay=0}if(s){s.loadTtip(ay)}J(ar.get(c)).removeClass("ws_overbull");J(ar.get(ay)).addClass("ws_overbull");ak.show();var az={left:ar.get(ay).offsetLeft-ak.width()/2,"margin-top":ar.get(ay).offsetTop-ar.get(0).offsetTop+"px","margin-bottom":-ar.get(ay).offsetTop+ar.get(ar.length-1).offsetTop+"px"};var ax=aj.get(ay);var aw={left:-ax.offsetLeft+(J(ax).outerWidth(true)-J(ax).outerWidth())/2};if(c<0){ak.css(az);f.css(aw)}else{if(!document.all){az.opacity=1}ak.stop().animate(az,"fast");f.stop().animate(aw,"fast")}c=ay}ar.hover(function(){ao(J(this).index())});var au;av.hover(function(){if(au){clearTimeout(au);au=0}ao(c)},function(){ar.removeClass("ws_overbull");if(document.all){if(!au){au=setTimeout(function(){ak.hide();au=0},400)}}else{ak.stop().animate({opacity:0},{duration:"fast",complete:function(){ak.hide()}})}});av.click(function(aw){ag(aw,J(aw.target).index())})}}}function M(c){J("A",Q).each(function(ak){if(ak==c){var ai=J(this);ai.addClass("ws_selthumb");if(!K){var f=Q.find(">div"),aj=ai.position()||{},al=f.position()||{};f.stop(true).animate({left:-Math.max(Math.min(aj.left,-al.left),aj.left+ai.width()-Q.width()),top:-Math.max(Math.min(aj.top,-al.top),aj.top+ai.height()-Q.height())})}}else{J(this).removeClass("ws_selthumb")}})}function Z(c){J("A",m).each(function(f){if(f==c){J(this).addClass("ws_selbull")}else{J(this).removeClass("ws_selbull")}})}if(C.caption){$caption=J("<div class='ws-title' style='display:none'></div>");k.append($caption);$caption.bind("mouseover",function(c){p()});$caption.bind("mouseout",function(c){H()})}var A=function(){if(this.filters){this.style.removeAttribute("filter")}};var R={none:function(f,c){c.show()},fade:function(ai,c,f){c.fadeIn(f,A)},array:function(ai,c,f){n(c,ai[Math.floor(Math.random()*ai.length)],0.5,"easeOutElastic1",f)},move:function(ai,c,f){R.array([{left1:"100%",top2:"100%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"-50%"},{top1:"-100%",top2:"100%",distance:0.7,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",top2:"-80%",distance:0.3,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",left2:"80%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"80%"}],c,f)},slide:function(ai,c,f){V(c,{direction:"left",easing:"easeInOutExpo",complete:function(){if(c.get(0).filters){c.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}},duration:f})}};R[0]=R.slide;function D(f){var aj=J("img",f).attr("title");var ai=J(f).data("descr");var c=J(".ws-title",k);c.stop(1,1).stop(1,1).fadeOut(C.captionDuration/3,function(){if(aj||ai){c.html((aj?"<span>"+aj+"</span>":"")+(ai?"<div>"+ai+"</div>":""));var ak=C.captionEffect;(R[J.type(ak)]||R[ak]||R[0])(ak,c,C.captionDuration)}})}function N(ak,f){var al,ai=document.defaultView;if(ai&&ai.getComputedStyle){var aj=ai.getComputedStyle(ak,"");if(aj){al=aj.getPropertyValue(f)}}else{var c=f.replace(/\-\w/g,function(am){return am.charAt(1).toUpperCase()});if(ak.currentStyle){al=ak.currentStyle[c]}else{al=ak.style[c]}}return al}function z(aj,ai,am){var al="padding-left|padding-right|border-left-width|border-right-width".split("|");var ak=0;for(var f=0;f<al.length;f++){ak+=parseFloat(N(aj,al[f]))||0}var c=parseFloat(N(aj,"width"))||((aj.offsetWidth||0)-ak);if(ai){c+=ak}if(am){c+=(parseFloat(N(aj,"margin-left"))||0)+(parseFloat(N(aj,"margin-right"))||0)}return c}function u(aj,ai,am){var al="padding-top|padding-bottom|border-top-width|border-bottom-width".split("|");var ak=0;for(var f=0;f<al.length;f++){ak+=parseFloat(N(aj,al[f]))||0}var c=parseFloat(N(aj,"height"))||((aj.offsetHeight||0)-ak);if(ai){c+=ak}if(am){c+=(parseFloat(N(aj,"margin-top"))||0)+(parseFloat(N(aj,"margin-bottom"))||0)}return c}function n(ak,ao,c,am,ai){var aj=ak.find(">span,>div").get();J(aj).css({position:"relative",visibility:"hidden"});ak.show();for(var f in ao){if(/\%/.test(ao[f])){ao[f]=parseInt(ao[f])/100;var an=ak.offset()[/left/.test(f)?"left":"top"];var ap=/left/.test(f)?"width":"height";if(ao[f]<0){ao[f]*=an}else{ao[f]*=k[ap]()-ak[ap]()-an}}}J(aj[0]).css({left:(ao.left1||0)+"px",top:(ao.top1||0)+"px"});J(aj[1]).css({left:(ao.left2||0)+"px",top:(ao.top2||0)+"px"});var ai=ao.duration||ai;function al(aq){var ar=J(aj[aq]).css("opacity");J(aj[aq]).css({visibility:"visible"}).css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:ar},ai,"easeOutCirc").animate({top:0,left:0},{duration:ai,easing:(ao.easing||am),queue:false})}al(0);setTimeout(function(){al(1)},ai*(ao.distance||c))}function V(an,aq){var ap={position:0,top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0};for(var ai in ap){ap[ai]=an.get(0).style[ai]}an.show();var am={width:z(an.get(0),1,1),height:u(an.get(0),1,1),"float":an.css("float"),overflow:"hidden",opacity:0};for(var ai in ap){am[ai]=ap[ai]||N(an.get(0),ai)}var f=J("<div></div>").css({fontSize:"100%",background:"transparent",border:"none",margin:0,padding:0});an.wrap(f);f=an.parent();if(an.css("position")=="static"){f.css({position:"relative"});an.css({position:"relative"})}else{J.extend(am,{position:an.css("position"),zIndex:an.css("z-index")});an.css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,right:"auto",bottom:"auto"})}f.css(am).show();var ao=aq.direction||"left";var aj=(ao=="up"||ao=="down")?"top":"left";var ak=(ao=="up"||ao=="left");var c=aq.distance||(aj=="top"?an.outerHeight(true):an.outerWidth(true));an.css(aj,ak?(isNaN(c)?"-"+c:-c):c);var al={};al[aj]=(ak?"+=":"-=")+c;f.animate({opacity:1},{duration:aq.duration,easing:aq.easing});an.animate(al,{queue:false,duration:aq.duration,easing:aq.easing,complete:function(){an.css(ap);an.parent().replaceWith(an);if(aq.complete){aq.complete()}}})}if(m.length||Q.length){e()}q(F);if(C.caption){D(i[F])}if(C.stopOnHover){this.bind("mouseover",function(c){p()});this.bind("mouseout",function(c){H()})}H(1);var I=k.find("audio").get(0);if(I){if(window.Audio&&I.canPlayType&&I.canPlayType("audio/mp3")){I.loop="loop";if(C.autoPlay){I.autoplay="autoplay";I.onload=function(){I.play()}}}else{I=I.src;var T=I.substring(0,I.length-/[^\\\/]+$/.exec(I)[0].length);var l="wsSound"+Math.round(Math.random()*9999);J("<div>").appendTo(k).get(0).id=l;var r="wsSL"+Math.round(Math.random()*9999);window[r]={onInit:function(){}};swfobject.createSWF({data:T+"player_mp3_js.swf",width:"1",height:"1"},{allowScriptAccess:"always",loop:true,FlashVars:"listener="+r+"&loop=1&autoplay="+(C.autoPlay?1:0)+"&mp3="+I},l);I=0}k.bind("stop",function(){if(I){I.pause()}else{J(l).SetVariable("method:pause","")}});k.bind("start",function(){if(I){I.play()}else{J(l).SetVariable("method:play","")}})}h.wsStart=j;h.wsStop=w;return this};jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f==0){return a}if(f==g){return a+h}if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a}return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a},easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a},easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a},easeOutElastic1:function(k,l,i,h,g){var f=Math.PI/2;var m=1.70158;var e=0;var j=h;if(l==0){return i}if((l/=g)==1){return i+h}if(!e){e=g*0.3}if(j<Math.abs(h)){j=h;var m=e/4}else{var m=e/f*Math.asin(h/j)}return j*Math.pow(2,-10*l)*Math.sin((l*g-m)*f/e)+h+i},easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a}});
```

plus jquery v1.8.3

Comment: please also add the code for your slideshow or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I've updated my post to include the code